How can I withdraw from ATM by my VakifBank card in the Philippines?
I have a VakifBank debit card. That is a Turkish bank, and my bank account involves US dollar, Euro, and GBP accounts too. And I can change the money in these currency to Turkish Lira through my bank application.
Now I am in the Philippines, and I want to withdraw money from ATM machines. How is that possible? Can I get Filipino Pesos from ATM? Which ATMs are best for this purpose? Should I do exchange through my application?

If my experience in other countries (Canada, Spain, China) is anything to go by: You can only withdraw or deposit local currency, at whatever fees and rate of exchange the bank which owns that ATM wants to charge (may be reasonable, may not be), plus whatever fees your own bank wants to charge (may be zero, may not be).
But that assumes your card connects to the networks that the ATM is on. Find out which it works with and find out if there are participating ATMs in the area you'll be visiting. It helps if your card can work through the credit card networks as well as the ATM networks.
Finding the best ATMs is entirely up to you, possibly with help from your bank back home and friends/co-workers/fellow ex-pats. There is no simple universal answer, and "best" may change at any moment. Personally, I would only worry about avoiding the obvious worst, and beyond that I'd walk into a local bank and ask them if they could assist with the transaction.
I'm not sure what "application" you're referring to.
